# Changing background of safe area without affecting keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

Is there a way in swiftui to change the background of the safe area edges without affecting the functionality of the keyboard?

I'm currently using .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) but that disables the movement of content when the keyboard is toggled, but if remove the .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) i have a white tab in the bottom of the screen.

Thanks

**EDIT: Added code**

```
struct LoginUser: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack {
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                Image("")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 150)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: signIn){
                    Text("Prisijungti")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .padding()
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                .stroke(colorScheme == . dark ? Color.black : Color.black, lineWidth: 2)
                        )
                }

                                .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                                    Alert(title: Text(alertTitle), message: Text(error), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // 1
            .padding()
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color(red: 246 / 255, green: 229 / 255, blue: 225 / 255))
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Unless you include a [mre], this is going to be challenging, if not impossible, to debug. Can you include the relevant code?

Comment: Hi, @jnpdx, i added the View

Comment: Can you pare this down into a [mre]?

Comment: The edit is closer (doesn't quite compile, but only requires a couple of changes), but it's not clear how to make the problem manifest. I added a `TextField` in my version to make the keyboard appear, but I'm not seeing any keyboard functionality adversely affected by your code.

Comment: Sorry, maybe the question is unclear, the keyboard is working, but i want to change the colour (now white) of the safe edges (devices like iphone X and up)

Comment: The safe edges are not white in the code you’ve included

Comment: Your code does not produce a white area for me. Where do you put your `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)`? Also there is no keyboard trigger in your code. Seems to me ,you are not showing us the code you use. As mentioned more than once,  show us a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).